# SQLlite db creating table error

Tags: android, sqlite

Hello i am working on a project in Android with SQLite.
I'm trying to created a db that (at the moment) has three tables : (TABLE_DR_TYPE,  TABLE_DR_TITLE, TABLE_USERS) I keep getting this error  in logcat when creating table USERS. Any help please?

```
    //TABLE DR TYPE
private static final String TABLE_DR_TYPE = "table_doctor_type";
private static final String DR_TYPE_COLUMN_ID = "id";
private static final String DR_TYPE_COLUMN_DR_TYPE = "dr_type";

// TABLE DOCTOR_TITLE
private static final String TABLE_DR_TITLE = "table_doctor_title";
private static final String DR_TITLE_COLUMN_ID = "id";
private static final String DR_TITLE_COLUMN_DR_TITLE = "dr_title";

// TABLE USERS
private static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
private static final String COLUMN_SURNAME = "surname";
private static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title_id"; // FK
private static final String COLUMN_DR_TYPE= "type_id"; // FK
private static final String COLUMN_PIN= "pin";
private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL= "email";
private static final String COLUMN_TEL= "telephone";

//CREATE TABLEs

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_DR_TYPE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_DR_TYPE + "("
        + DR_TYPE_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key, "
        + DR_TYPE_COLUMN_DR_TYPE + " text not null);";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_DR_TITLE= "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_DR_TITLE + "("
        + DR_TITLE_COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key, "
        + DR_TITLE_COLUMN_DR_TITLE + " text not null);";


private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_USERS + " ("
        + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_NAME + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_SURNAME + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_TITLE + " integer, "
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+COLUMN_TITLE+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_DR_TITLE+"("+DR_TITLE_COLUMN_ID+"), "
        + COLUMN_DR_TYPE + " integer, "
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+COLUMN_DR_TYPE+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_DR_TYPE+"("+DR_TYPE_COLUMN_ID+"), "
        + COLUMN_PIN + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_EMAIL + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_TEL + " text not null);";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    System.out.println("Kreiram bazu");
    db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DR_TYPE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DR_TITLE);
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);
    this.db = db;
}
```

logcat:

```
   Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "type_id": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE users (id integer primary key autoincrement, name text not null, surname text not null, title_id integer,  FOREIGN KEY (title_id) REFERENCES table_doctor_title(id), type_id integer,  FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES table_doctor_type(id), pin text not null, email text not null, telephone text not null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [diagram](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) the foreign key goes after the fields definition.

So the users table should be like this:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_USERS + " ("
        + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_NAME + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_SURNAME + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_TITLE + " integer, "          
        + COLUMN_DR_TYPE + " integer, "          
        + COLUMN_PIN + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_EMAIL + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_TEL + " text not null, "
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+COLUMN_TITLE+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_DR_TITLE+"("+DR_TITLE_COLUMN_ID+"), "
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+COLUMN_DR_TYPE+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_DR_TYPE+"("+DR_TYPE_COLUMN_ID+") "
        +");";
```

Comment: just wondering if using AUTOINCREMENT in query  is right thing or autoincrement